# Переопределение свойств метода в дочернем классе

Tags: php, ооп, наследование

Есть у меня класс A от которого наследуется класс B. Как мне переопределить некоторые свойства дочернего метода, допустим строку с sql запросом, а все остальное оставить тем же?

Comment: можно в вопрос немного код добавить как это представляется, что хочется? и написать зачем такое хочется? возможно вы что-то делаете не то, что нужно)

Comment: `переопределить некоторые свойства дочернего метода` - это правильно сформулировано?

Comment: @СергейВавилин а может пример покажете? А то вопрос не слишком корректно задали?

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно уловил суть вопроса, попробуйте так:

```
class A {
    public $prop = 'Parent property';
}

class B extends A {
    // объявите переменную с таким же именем, как и в родительском классе
    public $prop = 'Child property';
}

$obj = new B();
echo $obj->prop; // Child property
```

Comment: в вопросе и встречается слово "свойства", но на самом деле речь не об этом. Так что ответ не является верным